# Python websocket based application framework / server

Tags: javascript, python, frameworks, webserver, websocket

I want to write an 'cloud' based application to interactivly develop games. I'm developing apps and tools in Python for years, but so far they were not in 'client <-> server' model.

**I don not want to get any comparison. I want to ask experts, which tool is able to solve this specific problem**

I was digging for over two weeks for right solutions and I found a lot of different servers/frameworks. I'm new to client-server world, so I'm not able to judge the real strengths or weaknesses of these libraries.

I will heavly use websockets (Python on the server side, js on the client side) and I want to choose best possible Python server / framework.

The question is, which python server/framework:

1. will be suitable for big cloud based application development
2. will give me possibility to easly use websockets
3. will provide good scalability - I want to serve a lot of users
4. will give me good, sutiable framework for developing such application (or should I develop my own framework based on server like Tornado?)
5. will be fast (with above assumptions)
6. will allow me to use some websocket based 'rpc' solutions between client and server

The solutions I found during my research include:

- [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)
- [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/)
- [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/)
- [Cyclone](http://cyclone.io/)
- [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) + [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/)

Comment: worked in python for years and no client-server development? >.>

Comment: Yes. Not every project is based on client-server logic, especially when you're developing scientific tools.

Comment: I could understand limited client-server development, but ... none? Just seems odd.

Comment: @WojciechDanilo since you haven't selected any answer, can you please answer your own post and let us know what solution did you use and why ? I'm also looking for a websocket library with pretty much same requirements as yours.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Python only, then Twisted is a nice option to go with. Django has no web sockets implementation, though there are few projects at github, but still it is not recommended since Django runs on wsgi. Tornado is good with websockets too.

If you are at a beginning stage and exploring options, I strongly suggest, go with Node.js. It is awesome for asynchronous event handling. As name only suggests, its javascript not some python framework.

Comment: Our server application will be very complex, so I really want to develop it in Python, not JS. Or maybe you're talking about some JS-Python binding on the server side?

Comment: Node.js has nothing to do with Python. Actually Node.js is quite a recent upcoming for network based apps. Also, it has a vibrant community developing packages which are very elegantly managed by `npm`. If you are not in between of your project and are just about to start, give it a look. Even I switched from Python to Node.js that too in mid way. Node.js is `THE` option if you want scalability and your app would need higher concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with [Autobahn Websockets](http://autobahn.ws) (Twisted based) Framework. It has a clean implementation and it's well tested (Plus it has a JS client library).

Comment: Thank you, could you please provide a little more information why twisted should be better than tornado or gevent? (I'm talking about functionality and ease of use)

Comment: I have heard that Twisted learning curve is 'almost vertical' and maintance big applications is problem. Could you eleaborate a little bit about this topic also?

Answer (score 1):

You may try
  http://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html
There is a small demo using it with Python3.5 that I have uploaded
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BgpPm9N338s

Answer (score 0):

I worked a lot with Tornado webserver and SockJS as flexible transport layer (to provide websocket or "almost websocket" functionality for different browsers). This technical stack will solve #2, will be good basement for #4, and for #6. But from this point of view:

> suitable for big cloud based application development provide good
>
> scalability - I want to serve a lot of users

such points can be "resolved" with Python frameworks to some extent only. If you really need scalable real-time application which works fine with lot of users, I advice you to look at Erlang/OTP stack.

Comment: I'll probably stick with Python because of the heavy logic on the server side (my custom preference). Did you use Twisted or gevent? I'm concidering these 3 libraries right now.

Comment: I used Twisted and IMHO, it's not so pythonic as I want it be :) Gevent is useful for other types of applications, not for controlling concurrent states in websocket app.

Comment: Thank you! I would be very thankful for more information about gevent - for what kind of application is it useful?

Answer (score 0):

I am using **pywebsocket** , simple and small...

You can get the code here (96 KB) : http://code.google.com/p/pywebsocket/

*Tips:*

Try the standalone version than the Apache add-on version

If you need hixie support, add --allow-draft75 while starting the server